# The math behind Spearman-Karber method

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, decision-theory

A number of methods in my field use the [*Spearman-Karber method*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2044-8295.1908.tb00176.x) to estimate the minimum level of a variable needed for 50% success on a task. In addition to the original work, I have tried to increase my understanding based on the presentation by [Finney (1952)](http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/2048320/1/0041_6153.pdf), but both formulations of the underlying mathematics are hard for me to follow and there is something about the method that makes me uneasy. From what I can understand the estimated minimum level does not depend on what levels the successes and failures occur, but only on the number of successes. Intuitively, I feel like since the variance of a binomial random variable depends on the probability of success, the importance of a given observation should also depend on the probability of success.

Is there a current reference that explains the math underlying the Spearman-Karber method and any assumptions that are being made. Have there been computational simulations of the method?

Comment: What is your field?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala lets call it cognitive science.

Comment: could that be mentioned in the question?